# Disable informational logging in IdentityServer3

Tags: oauth-2.0, enterprise-library, identityserver3

I am using IdentityServer3(build 2.3.0.0) and Enterprise library for logging.
Currently, I have log options set as following

```
 var options = new IdentityServerOptions
    {
      LoggingOptions = new LoggingOptions()
      {
         EnableHttpLogging = false,
         EnableKatanaLogging = false,
         EnableWebApiDiagnostics = false,
         WebApiDiagnosticsIsVerbose = false
       },
       EventsOptions = new EventsOptions()
       {
         RaiseErrorEvents = true,
         RaiseFailureEvents = true,
         RaiseInformationEvents = false,
         RaiseSuccessEvents = false
       }
    }
```

Above configuration does not disable logging of following entries

```
Returning token response.
End token request
Creating JWT access token
Setting a sliding lifetime: 29100
Creating refresh token
Creating access token
Processing token request
Creating token response 
Start password token request validation
Start token request validation
Client validation success
Secret validator success: HashedSharedSecretValidator
Secret id found: JSApp
Parser found secret: PostBodySecretParser
Start parsing for secret in post body
X.509 certificate not found.
Start parsing for X.509 certificate
Start client validation
Start token request
CorsPolicyService allowed origin
```

How to disable above logging and just allow error logs entries only?

Comment: Your logging framework should have those filtering features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out how to configure EntLib configuration to avoid informational logging.

If `CategoryFilter` is used as a `logFilter` then you can disable Information logging by setting `switchValue` to `Warning`(or any other value per your need).

```
<add switchValue="Warning" name="Information">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Database Trace Listener" />
        </listeners>
</add>
```

If `PriorityFilter` is being used as `logFilter`, then one thing to note is that `LibLog` doesn't set priority parameter for `LogEntry`.

So, EntLib defaults `priority` to "-1".
But, EntLib does not filter LogEntries with `priority` with -1(even if `minimumPriority` is set to "-1").
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn440731(v=pandp.60).aspx

So, in this case logEntires endup at special category source

```
<specialSources>
    <allEvents switchValue="All" name="All Events" />
    <notProcessed switchValue="Warning" name="Unprocessed Category">
        <listeners>
             <add name="Database Trace Listener" />
        </listeners>
    </notProcessed>
    <errors switchValue="All" name="Logging Errors & Warnings"/>
</specialSources>
```

Here, set `notProcessed` category's `switchValue` to `Warning` to avoid informational logging.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a matter of configuring your logging framework to not display INFO logging. Instead log ERROR and FATAL only.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable logging altogether you can configure the NoopLogger for LibLog like:

`LogProvider.SetCurrent(new NoopLogProvider());`

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/master/source/Core/Logging/NoopLogProvider.cs

Comment: I believe this is introduced in v2.5.0.0. But, I am using 2.3.0.0.Anyways Thanks.

Comment: You can copy the source code - will also work with 2.3